# Looping over a function with several parameters

Tags: programming

Folks I am a beginner in Mathematica and have a simple question regarding loops: Here's the problem, I have a dataset of with four columns and I need to loop over each row. So the matrix in which my data is has dimensions of n*4,  (n rows).

If there was only one column then the problem is straightforward: I would do something like,

`For[i=1;x=0, i < n; i++, x = custF[i];Print[x]]`

where  `custF`  is custom function I built.

The problem is the function I built has four parameters not one. What I need is a loop like `ForEach`, which loops over each row and finds values of the function with all 4 parameters. Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: could you provide a small sample of your dataset? Is it correct to assume you want to pass row by row; meaning your custom function takes 4 arguments? Or do you want to pass element by element as they are found in rows?

Comment: Thanks for answering! so it's row by row. I do not it need element by element.

Comment: By "dataset" do you mean `Dataset`?

Comment: Okay, if you are using `Dataset` - how about `dataset[All, custF]`, where `dataset` is your dataset and `custF` is your function

Comment: Here's my datamatrix:

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9l6q1zi1iotjsa/Book1.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: It is described [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica) in great detail.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example:**

```
(*Arbitrary data*) 
list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {4, 4}]

(*Apply list to custom function*)
f @@@ list
```

**Output:**

> {f[2, 8, 6, 5], f[3, 1, 6, 7], f[9, 2, 10, 5], f[9, 2, 5, 9]}

**EDIT**

If you are loading an Excel spreadsheet, to apply row by row you could do something similar as described above.

In order to load up an Excel spreadsheet, see example below:

**Example:**

[image: dataset]

```
(*Import it into Mathematica*)
data =  Flatten[Import["C:\\Users\\-e\\Documents\\data.xlsx"], 1]
```

I use `Flatten` to remove additional `{}`

**Output:**

> {{1., 2., 3., 4.}, {3., 4., 5., 5.}, {7., 8., 7., 1.}, {4., 7., 3., 
>     6.}}

Then carry out same operation as in first example:

```
f @@@ data
```

where `f` is your custom function which takes 4 arguments as an input
and on the output of the above you should have something like:

> {f[1., 2., 3., 4.], f[3., 4., 5., 5.], f[7., 8., 7., 1.],   f[4., 7.,
>   3., 6.]}

**Reference:**

[Apply](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html?q=Apply)
[Flatten](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html?q=Flatten)
[List Manipulation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html)

**Tutorial:**

[Import spreadsheet](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ImportASpreadsheet.html)

Comment: Great! This works for my function. Any chance you could show me how to create the list with this dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9l6q1zi1iotjsa/Book1.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Solid stuff! Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome :)